# implied vol by Delta

Tags: options, implied-volatility, cds

I am looking at some data that is Delta 10, Delta 30, etc for an index option CDX IG. I know the meaning of Delta, as a sensitivity of the price move with respect $1 move in the underlying index. What does 10%, 30% mean in this case? Is that some subcase of the Delta I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is identical to how FX IVOL is quoted. See for example [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/15491/54838) or look at an illustration showing how FX options are quoted in [delta](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63662/54838). Uwe Wystup and Dimitri Reswich explains this [nicely](http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/FX/FX%20Volatility.pdf).

I am not too familiar with CDS options, but if you have Bloomberg, you can look at CDSO. Each delta corresponds to a specific strike / moneyness. The vol surface can be found on OMON for CDX's. CDX IG 5Y Corp >> OMON - Vol surface for example. If you display it in moneyness, or delta is usually a bit dependent on markets and conventions. In your case it seem you have IVOL quotes in terms of delta.